# Convert Array to Object with key name

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object, ecmascript-2018

**What is the best way to convert:**

```
[2019,2020,2021]
```

**to**

```
{
  0: {year:2019},
  1: {year:2020},
  2: {year:2021}
}
```

Comment: @Barmar The proposed answer doesn't quiet answers it, as the end result needs to be an object, not just values of the array.

Comment: OK, although it's a simple modification.

Comment: Why do you want an object with numeric keys instead of an array?

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
a = [2019,2020,2021];
a.reduce((acc, val, idx)=> {acc[idx] = {year: val}; return acc;}, {});
```

Comment: we are creating 1 object out of an array. So we are reducing the array. May would create another array. Though the question does raise the question of whether or not it should be an array instead of an object.

Answer (score 0):

Combination of `Object.assign()` and `array.map()` comes to mind:

```js
const array = [2019,2020,2021];

const object = Object.assign({}, array.map(a => ({year: a})));
console.log("object:", object);


const object2 = {}
array.forEach((a, i) => object2[i] = {year: a});
console.log("object2:", object2);
```